# How do I connect my Android Application to a MySQL database stored in a server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-connection, android-studio-3.0

Background on the MySQL database: it was created from a Wordpress website. As far as I know, it can only be accessed through PuTTy with the ff credentials given to me by my client who I’m making the app for:

1. hostname
2. port
3. my username to get into server
4. my password to
   get into server
5. mysql username
6. mysql password

---

It says from multiple sites that this is the PHP syntax to connect Android to MySQL

```
  // Connecting to mysql database
  $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
```

It does not work and when checked for the connection error, it shows the error “Connection timed out.” when I put credentials needed (hostname, mysql
username and password). I’m assuming it’s because I need to get into the server first (with credentials #3 and #4).

Is there a workaround to this?

EDIT:
This is only based on the assumption that I am supposed to create a PHP file (that I will place inside a Jave file in Android Studio) to connect to their database. Are there other ways to connect to a private server?

Comment: I would recommend you use https://yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check if the MySQL port is open, using the IP address of the server that hosts the database. The default port is 3306. Hosts rarely change the port. Another way to test it is by installing MySQL Workbench, and attempting to connect to it using that. If those tests work, then there may be another issue.
Honestly my PHP is a bit rusty, but from what I remember, your script looks correct.
And lastly, you said Android _and_ PHP, so does that mean you are running a PHP web server on an Android device?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Ateshi!

It sounds like you want an android app to directly access the mysql database that holds the content of a wordpress website.

The MySQL database server is most likely not publicly available on the internet for good reasons (security), as per this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63881/is-it-not-safe-to-open-mysqls-port-to-the-internet#63884)

You have posted some PHP code. PHP usually runs on the server alongside mysql, it not usually run on android.

Here is how you usually set up something like this:
Your android app makes a web request to http://yourexampleserver.com/example.php

Inside that example.php which is on the server, you have the PHP code that then does:
connects to mysql (with local credentials)
perhaps writes to the database
perhaps queries the database
formats the results into a useful format like JSON

The results are returned to java on your android which then usually shows them in the UI etc

This whole process is usually described as building a "webservice" for the app to use.

If however, you want the database contents to be stored offline and locally on android, then you probably need to connect to the server manually, export the database and download it, and then include it in your android project.

Comment: I do not know the backend of the server since I was just added as a new user to it by my client (owner of the server). I assumed I had to create a new PHP file to connect to it and add it to my Java file in Android. Are you saying that there is already a PHP file automatically made in the server?

Comment: PHP is usually a server-side language, you have to make the example.php on the server yourself. Then you have to code android to request that php file. There are many tutorials online for this, perhaps try searching on google or youtube for "android mysql php tutorial" or similar.